# My Kubernetes Public Service not accessible anymore

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes

I have had my Application running on Google Cloud Platform on Compute engine for a while now
`service        XX.XX.XXX.XX    107.167.189.109   80/TCP     121d`
Its a Kubernetes Cluster. Everything was working fine, I didn't touch anything and now all other sudden the site can't be reached. http://107.167.189.109/#/api/v1/category 
I haven't look at my site in a couple of month now (I was on holidays) I am a paying customer for this service. Is it that if no one visite the site for a while the access is revoked ?  I can't understand why the site is down when the only thing I did was not checking it. Is there an "Idle" mechanism starting if a service is not access for a while ? How do I debug this ? Thanks

Comment: You can try contacting support. Have you tried looking at the Network > External IP addresses page in your cloud console?

Comment: Here are some tips for debugging your service http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/application-troubleshooting/#debugging-services

Answer (score 0):

I turned out that the `kubectl get pods` was returning status running on my Replication Controllers but they were down (I suppose...). I kill and restarted the whole cluster and everything is back to normal. I sad though the the status was lying.